# assign array to structure pointer

Tags: c++, structure

Getting segmentation fault while trying to print content member using pointer l_pContent in below program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

struct responseStruct {

    int Handle;
    int headerLen;
    int bodyLen;
    unsigned char* content;
};

int main()
{
    unsigned char l_httpResponse[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l',0};
    struct responseStruct *l_pContent = (struct responseStruct*)l_httpResponse;
    cout << l_pContent->content << endl;  // Error : Segmentation Fault
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's why C-style casts are bad. `(struct responseStruct*)l_httpResponse;` can't be legally casted to a `responseStruct` pointer that way. You need to take the address: `(struct responseStruct*)&l_httpResponse;`

Comment: I don't know C++, but how this is spoosed to work anyway? one is a struct, another is an array.

Comment: Thanks Sourav for your reply, 
am still getting segmentation fault by doing below assignment.

struct responseStruct *l_pContent = (struct responseStruct*)&l_httpResponse;

Answer (score 1):

The variable `content` is a pointer to an `unsigned char` and so is `l_httpResponse`. You can therefore create an instance of the `responseStruct` and then assign the instance's `content` pointer to `l_httpResponse`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

struct responseStruct {
    int Handle;
    int headerLen;
    int bodyLen;
    unsigned char* content;
};

int main()
{
    unsigned char l_httpResponse[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l',0};

    // Create instance of an responseStruct struct
    responseStruct rs;

    // Make content point to the start of l_httpResponse
    rs.content = l_httpResponse;

    // Test for access without segfault
    cout << static_cast<unsigned>(rs.content[1]) << endl;  
    return 0;
}
```

Or here is a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Omitting the fact that the idea of such code is mysterious to me, here is what causes the error:
If we assume that members of the `responseStruct` will match ideally the data from the `l_httpResponse`, that `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(unsigned char *)`  are 4, that your architecture uses little-endian notation, and that your compiler uses ASCII (which it probably does), you end with:

```
Handle == 0x04030201
headerLen == 0x08070605
bodyLen == 0x02010009
content == 0x64636261
```

Now, `content` is a pointer, so 0x64636261 is an address in your memory. It doesn't point to your "abcde..." string. It's made up of it's first four bytes. And points at some non existing region. That's why you end up with segmentation fault.